# How to create an instance of a Decoder?

Tags: swift

There is struct from another module that I would like to initialize. It doesn't have a public `init()` method but I can create it from decoding JSON.

```swift
struct Foo: Codable {
    let name: String
    let details: String
}
```

I have created a static function to create an instance

```swift
extension Foo {
    static func create(name: String) throws -> Self {
        let dictionaryRep = ["name": name, "details": ""]
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionaryRep, options: [])
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Is there instead a way to create a new init method to create a new instance?

```swift
extension {
   public init(name: String) throws {
      try self.init(from: <#Decoder#>)
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, `Decoder` is a protocol, therefore you have to create a class/struct conforming to `Decoder` and use that.
It is probably easier to create a mock JSON data and decode that, as you have done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Foo` is a `struct` (not a `class`), your initializer can assign to `self` like this:

```
extension Foo {
    init(name: String) throws {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["name": name, "details": ""])
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Comment: @joels if your intent is to initialize a struct from a json object `init(jsonObject: Any) throws {` `self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject))` `}` or if your intend is to initialize it from json data returned from the API `init(data: Data) throws {` `self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus The only public init available it init(from decoder: Decoder). My intent is to initialize the struct so I’m working around the fact that I have to initialize from json.

Comment: @joels have you tried initialising each property?

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, thanks. I get "'self.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer." because the only publicly available init available is init(from:)

Comment: In this case you have no option. Anyway the last two initializers I have posted above are the way to go. You can initialize from an object (dictionary or array) or from json data

Comment: Neither of the `init`s in your comment is what joels asked for: an `init` that takes a `name` string.